# How to have margins not offset my grid

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently working on a game where squares are made to advance in the game. Currently, I am trying to figure out how to make it so the boxes do not have an offset when they are shown. Instead I want them to be in an equal grid. I can not figure out how to get rid of this annoying offset. My code is as follows:

JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<body>
<div id = "square1" class = "gridsquare">
<div class = "gridsquarecontent" id = "square1content">
Welcome to Idle Grid! An exponentially complex idle displayed through stylish boxes! This cute little square is the one to get new squares. <button onclick = "$('#square2').show();document.getElementById('square1content').innerHTML =  'Nice! Use your new square to afford the next one!'" id = "btn-1">Get a new square</button>
</div>
</div>
<div id = "square2" class = "gridsquare">
<div class = "gridsquarecontent">
Git gud
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>$("#square2").hide()</script>
```

CSS:

```
body{width:820px;height:820px;border-color:black;border-width:0px;border-style:solid;margin:5px;font-family:arial;font-size:14px;margin-top:0px}
.gridsquare{width:200px;height:200px;border-color:black;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;display:inline-block;overflow:none;background-color:white;margin-top:5px}
.gridsquarecontent{margin:10px;overflow:none}
button{background-color:white;border-color:Black;border-width:1px;display:block;margin-top:5px;transition: background-color,color 0.3s}
button:hover{outline:0;background-color:black;color:white}
button:focus{outline:0}
```

Comment: I added a float:left; to gridsquare that seems to fix it. See if this solves your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/qbbfxkbf/   (not sure what you are going for)

Comment: Do you have the same result in every major browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have an active area (a holder div with it's own rule that specifies width) and load your squares under that parent element. Then just add float:left on the .gridsquare rule and the squares will fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of margins >0. Set them to zero and increase only those that you need for positioning. Right now I think you have a case of margin "stacking".
 Zero out your "stack" and start with the most important margins first, then add more only as needed.
 Remember that margins tend to push objects around if there is a tight fit.